# Adding Material Slot: Nothing happens

Tags: materials

I am trying to assign multiple materials to an object (to different faces). I understand that I have to have multiple materials, and multiple material slots with these materials assigned.

However, I am having trouble creating a material slot in the first place. I select my object, then, still in object mode, I go to Materials tab, then press + on the right of the slot list (A). Nothing happens (i.e. no slot appears in the list) (B).

[image: Blender Material Slots]

I thought it might be that I have no material yet, so I pressed the "+ NEW" button below the slot list (C), created a new material, and with it still showing, clicked the + (A) on the right of the slot list again. Nothing happens (i.e. no slot appears in the list).

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you using the Cycles rendering engine or the Blender internal?

Comment: By the way, if on Cycles, you add a new mat slot, create a new mat (if you wish) then go to _edit mode_ in the mesh, go to _face mode_ and select the faces you want the material to be assigned to, then you will see _Assign_, _Select_, _Deselect_. Click _assign_ and you should be fine.

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter which rendering engine I use. As for the Assign/Select/Deselect: Yes, I see them; but as I don't have a material slot, clicking them doesn't do anything.

Comment: Is this object linked in from another blend?

Comment: @David no; it was however imported from a .stl file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phil, I add below a capture of how it should be behaving (both on blender render or cycles render): if it does not work like this, something went wrong, either the blender install itself or something else...

[image]

Comment: That is how I thought it should look like ;-) I now exported my model as an FBX, reimported it into a new .blend file, and there the material slot does indeed appear. Something seems to have gone very wrong in my first .blend file. Rather weird. Thanks, this helped!

Comment: When making a gif that includes button presses it would be a good idea to include the mouse pointer.

Comment: @David I agree, I'm using LICEcap on linux (through wine) and I can't see the option... is it possible, how?

Comment: @David I just found key-mon (https://github.com/critiqjo/key-mon), it seems quite useful for tutorial-like screen recording... I'll try to update the gif video, tomorrow...  thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @m.ardito odd, I use licecap (on windows) and it captures the mouse pointer.

Comment: @David I tried licecap on windows, today, and both the cursor and mouse click press are recorded... updated the above gif.